# How can I fix the vi editor in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, vi

recently I was trying to run a c program using cygwin.  The program called for a function fopen_s().  After compiling, I kept getting errors that this function did not exist.  I did a bunch of trouble shooting but ultimately decided to just update cygwin since my version was kind of old.  I did all of that and opened vi.  while in vi the insert command wont work.  I keep hitting 'i' but it just types 'i' to the screen.  Backspace does not remove it, typing extra characters just creates undefined behavior.  I can ':q!' to close vi, but so far I can't write a program.

Any ideas?

I just installed cygwin gcc-8.3.0, following the build instructions from https://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `vim`  ?

Comment: @Philippe I don't have vim installed in my cygwin, I ran the command "vim test.c" just to check, but it came back as command not found.

Comment: Can you try to install it. It's much better than vi.

Comment: one question at time, with clear : what did you do, what is the expectation and the current result for anyone to replicate and verify. About fopen_s https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/compatibility.html#std-susv4 I doubt it is available in Cygwin, but I can not check in this moment to be sure

Comment: @matzeri When I " : " I enter the command " :q! " I expect it to quit and not save the file. For example, in this case, I start with: "vi myProgram.c // I hit enter"; the editor opens, I hit " i " for insert.  I expect to be able to be able to type code; I hit keys, the letter show on screen.  I make an error, I hit backspace, the cursor moves back but the char remains.  I press right arrow to get in front of the char, and a capital letter "C" is printed to the screen on a new line.  I hit backspace, the cursor moves behind the cap "C" instead of deleting it.

Comment: @matzeri Thank you for the insight on Cygwin and fopen_s, that was news to me.  Do you know of a better options then Cygwin that I could use instead?  Thank you.